# How to efficiently implement a sub-pixel convolution layer in a CNN for image super-resolution

Tags: neural-networks

I am playing around using convolution neural networks for image super-resolution, i.e. up-scaling of images.  In literature I often come across the concept of sub-pixel convolution as one of the layers in CNNs for super-resolution.  If you want to upscale by a factor r, the idea is to merge r^2 feature maps by interleaving them into a single image.  Below is an example of 4 feature maps of 3x3 being merged into a single 6x6 image (i.e. scaling factor of 2). This can be extended to bigger scaling factors.

I have been looking at available neural network layers in MMA 12.1, but I have not figured out how to implement a sub-pixel convolution with the available layers.  Maybe the use of a deconvolution layer with a clever choice of a fixed kernel and strides might do the trick but I can't see how yet.

Did anybody in the MMA community already try to implement a sub-pixel convolution efficiently, or maybe point me in some direction how to implement it using the available NN layers.

[image: principle of sub-pixel convolution]

Answer (score 6):

You are right that the sub-pixel convolution can be achieved with deconvolution layers with fixed weights

```
net = NetGraph[{
   "part1" -> PartLayer[1],
   "part2" -> PartLayer[2],
   "part3" -> PartLayer[3],
   "part4" -> PartLayer[4],
   "dcov1" -> 
    DeconvolutionLayer["Weights" -> {{{{1, 0}, {0, 0}}}}, 
     "Biases" -> None, "Stride" -> 2],
   "dcov2" -> 
    DeconvolutionLayer["Weights" -> {{{{0, 1}, {0, 0}}}}, 
     "Biases" -> None, "Stride" -> 2],
   "dcov3" -> 
    DeconvolutionLayer["Weights" -> {{{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}}}, 
     "Biases" -> None, "Stride" -> 2],
   "dcov4" -> 
    DeconvolutionLayer["Weights" -> {{{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}}}, 
     "Biases" -> None, "Stride" -> 2],
   "sum" -> TotalLayer[]
   }, {"part1" -> "dcov1" -> "sum", "part2" -> "dcov2" -> "sum", 
   "part3" -> "dcov3" -> "sum", "part4" -> "dcov4" -> "sum"}]
```

[image]

```
data = {{{{2, 1, 5}, {4, 0, 9}, {3, 0, 0}}}, {{{4, 3, 0}, {0, 1, 
      7}, {2, 8, 4}}}, {{{5, 8, 9}, {1, 3, 2}, {0, 1, 6}}}, {{{0, 4, 
      1}, {7, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 3}}}};

net[data][[1]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]